# Ubuntu 14.04 with gtx 670 slow window animations

Tags: unity, 14.04, nvidia, compiz

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed on an i5 2500k, 8GB ram and gtx 670. The problem is that all the window animations are very slow. For example when trying to resize a window is like it will take hours to complete the action.

I have already installed the latest nvidia drivers (340).

The weird thing is that whenever I change the driver (to whatever else) from "Additional Drivers", then everything is great (very smooth movement and window resizing), but after reboot everything is so slow again.

Any ideas?

Here are some information.

```
-------------------------------------------
lspci -vnn | grep -i VGA -A 12
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 [GeForce GTX 670] [10de:1189] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Palit Microsystems Inc. Device [1569:1189]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 49
    Memory at f9000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]
    Memory at ee000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at af00 [size=128]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at e8000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia

01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 HDMI Audio Controller [10de:0e0a] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Palit Microsystems Inc. Device [1569:1189]
-------------------------------------------

glxinfo | grep OpenGL | grep renderer
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GTX 670/PCIe/SSE2
-------------------------------------------
```

thank you!